# Why do my loss and accuracy seem to be unrelated?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN for predicting CIFAR10 classes, which I've adapted from a working solution for the MNIST data-set.

The model is *image->conv->pool->conv->pool->FC->dropout->FC->class_prediction*, which I assume would do substantially better than a fully-connected net (which I was achieving ~50% with when doing the [CS231 course](http://cs231n.github.io)).

I'm receiving some strange results, where the accuracy and loss don't really seem to be linked to one-another: [training accuracy and loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihXR4.png)

As shown, the loss keeps dropping, which is a good thing, but it doesn't seem to really affect the accuracy, even on the training set.

Sorry for dumping this all here, but below I've extracted all the code I believe to be relevant. So please let me know if I can add any further information.

```
with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    # Construct model
    pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    # Define loss function and optimizer
    net = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y_true, name='Softmax_Loss')
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(net)

with tf.name_scope('Adam_Descent'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, name='Adam_Descent').minimize(cost)   

# Evaluate the model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

#
# Code omitted
#

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    step = 1
    # Train for a while
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:

        batch_x, batch_y = get_rand_train_batch(batch_size, 10000)

        # Run optimization        
        _, summary = sess.run([optimizer, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, 
                                                                         y_true: batch_y, 
                                                                         keep_prob: 0.75})
        if step * index % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, 
                                                              y_true: batch_y, 
                                                              keep_prob: 1})
            print_blue("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:2.3f}%".format(acc*100))
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step * batch_size)
        step += 1

    # Calculate test accuracy
    print("\nTesting Accuracy:", \
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_test[:1000],
                                  y_true: y_test[:1000],
                                  keep_prob: 1.}))
```

Comment: Maybe it is overfitting. Have you tried cross-validation?

Comment: Could you post us a rescaled loss graph - like log-error or loss history since when error is not bigger than 10? This scales make your graph hard to interpret.